# dotnet publish for ASP.NET Core project doesn't publish on FileSystem

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-publish

When using the command

```
dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=CustomProfile
```

my ASP.NET Core project builds and gets published using the `FileSystem` publishing method.

When I use the

```
dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=CustomProfile
```

command (which should do the publish part only) the build part gets done but no publish actions are done.

Is this a limitation from dotnet?
Is there a workaround?

My system:

```
dotnet --version
3.1.201
```

VS2019 16.5.3